# react-native error:[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Error encountered while fetching Expo token: TypeError: Network request failed.]

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, expo

```
Error logs: [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Error encountered while fetching Expo token: TypeError: Network request failed.]
* [native code]:null in construct
- node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\construct.js:19:9 in _construct
- node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\wrapNativeSuper.js:26:22 in Wrapper
* [native code]:null in construct
* http://192.168.1.4:19015/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:107658:321 in _createSuperInternal
- node_modules\@unimodules\react-native-adapter\build\errors\CodedError.js:8:8 in constructor
- node_modules\expo-notifications\build\getExpoPushTokenAsync.js:35:22 in fetch._catch$argument_0
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:135:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:183:16 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:446:30 in callImmediates
* [native code]:null in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:396:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:144:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:143:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

my code:

```
  import Constants from "expo-constants";
    import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
    import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    import { MainLayout } from "./src/MainLayout";
    //TODO import fonts
    /*var uuid = require('react-native-uuid');
    console.log(uuid.v4())*/
    
    export default function App() {
      registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then((token) => console.log(token));
      return <MainLayout />;
    }
    
    async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
      let token;
      if (Constants.isDevice) {
        const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
          Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
        );
        let finalStatus = existingStatus;
        if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
          const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
          finalStatus = status;
        }
        if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
          alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
          return;
        }
        token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
        console.log(token);
      } else {
        alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
      }
    
      if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
          name: "default",
          importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
          vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
          lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
        });
      }
    
      return token;
    }
```

I wanted to implement a notification push mechanism, took the code from this site https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to look at this issue: https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications/issues/440, specifically the comment I left here: https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications/issues/440#issuecomment-680415269